# SQLite reduce time in for loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite

this code reads out all entrys of my sqlite table and puts them into a list. I've tried to reduce the loading time with Threads and checking all of them to be finished with join() before returning my list. But if I do the querys as Threads i get some entrys twice.

```
public ArrayList<ModelTura_spieler> getAllTura_spieler() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    final ArrayList<ModelTura_spieler> tura_spielerList = new ArrayList<ModelTura_spieler>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tura_spieler";
    final Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        for(c.moveToFirst(); c.getPosition()!=getTura_spielerCount()-1  ; c.moveToNext()){
                    ModelTura_spieler tura_spieler = getModelTura_spielerFromCursor(c);
                    tura_spielerList.add(tura_spieler);
                }
    return tura_spielerList;
}
```

How to reduce the query time of this for loop with Threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Sqlite is not Thread-Safe, that means your SQLiteHelper locks your database by default.

The reason is that you can only access by one connection/transaction at a time.

Define the fields you want to grab to make it slightly faster using:

```
SELECT field1,field2,anotherfield FROM tura_spieler
```

You may also want to have an [index](https://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) which boost your speed aswell.

If you want to query fields based on some others you want to join them.

If you'r new to Android and Sqlite you should take a look to a new android library called [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) which provides a easy-to-use [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html)